# Moving indexes between ElasticSearch clusters

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've installed logstash locally and I'm attempting to copy an index between elasticsearch clusters.

I have a local elasticsearch configured on port 9210 and a remote ES cluster hosted in IBM Bluemix. I've setup the logstash.conf as below:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9210" ]
    index => "lon02-daily-2017.08.30"
    size => 500
    scroll => "5m"
    docinfo => true
  }
}

output {
  # We write to the "new" cluster
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://xxxxxxx:19459/"]
    user => "xxxxxx"
    password => "xxxxxxx"
    index => "%{[@metadata][_index]}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
  }
  # We print dots to see it in action
  stdout {
    codec => "dots"
  }
}
```

However when I run ./logstash -f logstash.conf I get the following error (posted below) which suggests that logstash can't connect to the remote cluster, however I can contact it via curl as below:
curl -u xxxxxx:xxxxxxx https://xxxxxxx:19459/

```
Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at
["https://xxxx:19459/"]', but an error occurred and it failed! 
Are you sure you can reach elasticsearch from this machine using the configuration provided?
```

I think means that logstash isn't using the credentials in logstash.conf. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: ES and logstash versions?